# Illustrator exported .svg files won't render in HTML

Tags: html, css, svg, adobe-illustrator

I am not sure if this is a coincidence, but it seems that if I export svg files from Illustrator or even try to use svg files I find on the web that were exported from Illustrator, they don't render.

I am using the code below, maybe someone with in-depth knowledge of svg and HTML can tell me what might be wrong with my svg file?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <style>
    html {
      background-image: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7146901/svgbkgnd%5B1%5D.svg);
      background-size: contain;
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  <head>......</head>
</html>
```

I have tried the code above and replaced the link to a different svg file and it works, so my guess is that something is wrong with my svg file specifically?

Comment: Why are you applying the CSS to the `html` element and not the `body`?

Comment: I want a background for the entire page, not just the body.  Regardless, the markup above works with different svg files, so it appears there is something wrong with this file and I want to try to deduce what that is but haven't the slightest idea where to start.

Comment: Um. If it isn't in the `body` it will not render. Only stuff in the `body` element shows up.

Comment: I believe that statement is incorrect.  I have used the same markup with images and other svg files and it has rendered fine.  As a test I also tried changing it to the body but the svg still does not render.

Comment: @Oded:  [ Disclaimer--I'm not a css guru. ]  As I understand it, you and mvcNewbie are both correct. You can add a background-image to the html. But you are also correct because if you put your background-image into the body and it will elevate to the full html viewport as long as you don't also specify a background-color in the body.  Let me know if I'm wrong...I like to learn!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as expected. See http://jsfiddle.net/PA8zn/show Here I've included the SVG on the HTML element:

```
html {
    background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7146901/svgbkgnd%5B1%5D.svg) no-repeat;
```

}

The SVG is a very heavy file, so it takes quite a while to show up. You could try cleaning it up to improve performance. Either by hand or with a tool like Scour: http://codedread.com/scour/

Comment: Ditto your result, shows fine on IE10/win7--slow loading though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the jsfiddle dstorey, I had been messing around with it all day and your simple example helped, maybe it could have been part to how I was serving up the content.